# Rename one particular column of a matrix in Stata

Tags: stata

I am working on modyfinyg, renaming and arranging estimation results for final publication in Stata. What I have so far is:

```
sysuse auto, clear

* interaction model
gen int_mpg_mpg = mpg*mpg // generate interaction manually 
qui regress price weight mpg int_mpg_mpg foreign 
mat b=e(b) // store estimation results in matrix b 
matrix list b // see the problem, colum 3 "int_mpg_mpg"
    
b[1,5]
         weight          mpg  int_mpg_mpg      foreign        _cons
y1    3.0379251   -298.14637    5.8617627    3420.2156   -527.04589


* rename interaction with additional package erepost 
local coln "b:weight b:mpg b:c.mpg#c.mpg b:foreign b:_cons"
mat colnames b= `coln'
capt prog drop replace_b
program replace_b, eclass
erepost b= b, rename
end
replace_b
eststo my_model 

esttab my_model, label
```

This gives a nice version of the interaction term:

```
------------------------------------
                              (1)   
                            Price   
------------------------------------
b                                   
Weight (lbs.)               3.038***
                           (3.84)   

Mileage (mpg)              -298.1   
                          (-0.82)   

Mileage (mpg) # Mi~)        5.862   
                           (0.90)   

Car type                   3420.2***
                           (4.62)   

Constant                   -527.0   
                          (-0.08)   
------------------------------------
Observations                   74   
------------------------------------
```

But imagine that I have many more models and variables. Then it becomes very unhandy to list all variables, all interactions etc. in this local `coln`

```
local coln "b:weight b:mpg b:c.mpg#c.mpg b:foreign b:_cons"
mat colnames b= `coln'
```

I am trying to only fix particular column names in the estimation matrix:

```
local colfix "b:c.mpg#c.mpg"
mat colnames b[1,3]= `colfix'
```

How can I access a particular column of a matrix in Stata?

Comment: I don't understand this, why not just use the `varlabels` option?

Comment: `varlabels` can adjust the labels but does not combine equal ones (as far as I tested).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intended new name seems the same as the existing name.

I don't know a way to change individual column names, but this may help:

```
. matrix foo = J(3, 4, 42)

. matrix colname foo = frog toad DRAGON griffin

. mat li foo

foo[3,4]
       frog     toad   DRAGON  griffin
r1       42       42       42       42
r2       42       42       42       42
r3       42       42       42       42

. local colnames : colnames foo

. local colnames : subinstr local colnames "DRAGON" "newt", all

. matrix colname foo = `colnames'

. matrix li foo

foo[3,4]
       frog     toad     newt  griffin
r1       42       42       42       42
r2       42       42       42       42
r3       42       42       42       42
```

It's a modest exercise to make that into a subroutine. The bigger deal is whether there is a way to do this in the `estout` suite, wonderful commands I never use.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the excellent suggestion. The `subinstr` approach is working in principle for continuous variables (not for factors). I'm thinking about it.